# Unwanted submit on key up in Icefaces 3.0

Tags: events, icefaces, onkeyup

I use Icefaces 3.0, and I have an annoying problem. The ice:inputText component of Icefaces always (even without `partialSubmit` set to true) registers an onkeyup Javascript event handler on the output like this:

```
onkeyup="iceSubmit(form,this,event);"
```

It's okay, it does not bother me. But, if I use a validator, things can go wrong.
If I have a validator on e.g. another ice:inputtext, every time I type in a non english or special character (like $), icefaces submits the value, and validation occurs on the whole form. Namely icefaces generates a full submit on the view.
Even more interesting: if I just type in english characters, nothing happens. No full submit, not even partial, which is the expected behaviour.

My question is: How can I disable this behaviour? Of course, I can add `onkeyup="return false;"` in my XHTML to every input component, but that looks like overkill to me.
Thanks!